# Is there anyway to recover source files from Apple IOS Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I had a macbook pro and I developed an app on that laptop. I had all of the source files on that macbook. But the mac was destroyed. Is there any way of getting the published files from Apple? If that is not possible, if I wanted to create a new app using a different laptop, could I still publish to the same app creating an update through Apple?

Comment: First,If you do not have a Time Machine backup, it is not possible to recover the files. Second, yes you can publish the update if you know the bundle identifier of the app!

Comment: Is there anyway to retrieve the bundle identifier?

Comment: U can get it from iTunes connect